# PHP Error - Exception: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, static-methods

Hi i'm having this error with this example code.

Exception: Using $this when not in object context

```
<?php

Class A {
 public function test($str)
 {
     return trim($str);
 }
}


Class B {

 protected $trim;   
 public function __construct(A $trim){  
     $this->trim = $trim;
 }   

 public static function trim_str($str)
 {
     return $this->trim->test($str);
 }
}

//implementation
B::trim_str(" TRIM ME ");

?>
```

anyone can enlighten me.
thanks

Comment: `$this` refers to an instance of a given object. But static is not really related to an instance, so you can't use `$this` in a static method.

Comment: how can i refactor the code? instantiate the Class A inside the static method? is it a good practice?

Comment: remove static and try

Comment: @sonal i aim the class to be a helper class. i chose to use it as a static so i wouldn't instantiate it every time i call it.

Comment: Replace the content of `trim_str` with `$a = new A(); return $a->test($str);`.

Comment: But your code needs elaboration, Why would you create a parameter in the construct and never use it? Besides, if you intend on using an attribute of an object, you can't have the method as static.You've got to rethink what you are trying to do here.

Comment: oh i see, how would you do it? a helper class with a dependency with other class? what would be the best approach. thanks for the input btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class B
{

    protected $trim;

    public function __construct(A $trim)
    {
        $this->trim = $trim;
    }

    public static function trim_str($str)
    {
        return $this->trim->test($str); //You Cannot access $this here
    }
}
```

**Possible Solution**

Change **$trim** variable to static

```
Class B
{
    protected static $trim;

    public function __construct(A $trim)
    {
        static::$trim = $trim;
    }

    public static function trim_str($str)
    {
        return static::$trim->test($str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use `$this` in the context of the static method in a class as it does not belong to an instance that's why the error occurs.

As per PHP manual :

Because static methods are callable without an instance of the class, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

Please refer to PHP manual documentation for a brief description (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)